# vmware guest cpu speed not reflecting reserved speed settings

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2016

I created a windows server 2016 vm in vmware and set the cpu to 3,000 mhz in the vm settings. When I open task manager on the VM it only shows 2.20 ghz as the CPU speed. Why is that?

Comment: Assuming you mean the VMware product ESXi here.  Reserved means that's only the amount the VM is guaranteed, not required to use.  If the reservation is set to 3000Mhz, when the virtual machine needs 3000Mhz, it is guaranteed to get it. ESXi will steal CPU cycles from other virtual machines to fulfill the guaranteed reservation of 3000Mhz.

Comment: Thank you. I was installing software on this VM and it says the VM does not meet the minimum requirements of 2.6 ghz even though I reserved 3 ghz for the vm. I amo not sure why it does not detect the cpu speed allocated.

Comment: I was not aware of the host we have only had a 2.2 ghz processor.